# Is there any multiple pagination on the same page but in different tabs in django?

Tags: django, django-pagination, tabbedpage

I have tabs in a Django template displaying the tour packages category. For a single page, I am able to implement pagination in Django, but I do not know how to make pagination based on tabs. Any suggestions on how to filter in Django views based on tabbed heading?

In a single page, I am using it like so:

`models.py`:

```py
def blog(request):
    blog_list = Blog.objects.filter(blog_verification=True)
    paginator = Paginator(blog_list, 6)  # Show 6 blogs per page.
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {'blogs': page_obj, 'packages': Packages.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'user/blog.html', context)
```

Templates:

```html
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if blogs.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ blogs.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ blogs.number }} of {{ blogs.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if blogs.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ blogs.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        <a href="?page={{ blogs.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you looking to have happen? Please try to be detailed as I don't understand what you're looking for. Perhaps include the ideal HTML that would be rendered?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506609/how-organize-pagination-with-a-large-number-of-pages-in-django-project/63507365#63507365) may help you